# one text box with tow option different in value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a form contain a textbox with tow option, one of the options is to write a just letter and the other option is to write a number, how can separate them?

when the user selected journal name it should write just a letter and when select ISSN it will enter a just number?
function ValidateTextBox(txt)
{

```
if (txt == "ISSN") {
    document.getElementById("searchword").pattern="[0-9]{4}[-]{1}[0-9]{3}[0-9Xx]{1}";
      document.getElementById("searchword").placeholder="like: 1111-1111 or 1111-111x";
}
 else {
      document.getElementById("searchword").pattern="[A-Za-z]{100}";
    document.getElementById("searchword").placeholder="International journal of Computers and Technology";

}
```

}

function inputLimiter(e,allow) {
  var AllowableCharacters = '';

    if (allow == 'Letters'){AllowableCharacters=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';}

    var k = document.all?parseInt(e.keyCode): parseInt(e.which);
    if (k!=13 && k!=8 && k!=0){
        if ((e.ctrlKey==false) && (e.altKey==false)) {
        return (AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k))!=-1);
        } else {
        return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

Comment: Sounds like you want to validate the element's value when onkeyup or onchange is triggered. What have you tried?

Comment: the html code:
<h4 style="color:  rgb(204,72,8) ; font-size: 25px; margin-left: -140px "> Search of journal to update: </h4>
<p><input type="text" name="searchword" size="50" maxlength="200"  id="searchword" required> by <select  name="searchway"onchange="ValidateTextBox(this.value);">
<option value="JournalName" selected>Journal Name</option>
<option value="ISSN">ISSN</option>
</select></p>

Comment: @kainaw when the user selects journal name option it will be entering a letter and space and he can enter a number, but when he selects ISSN option it will be entering a number.

Answer (score 0):

Check This http://jsfiddle.net/pjkhpxzx/ When A User Select A Value In Drop Down That Value Will Be Visible In The Text Box

This Done By A Simple JQuery

Below Is HTML

```
<select id="data">
    <option value=""></option>
<option value="text">text</option>
<option value="number">number</option>
```

below is Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#data").change(function(){
var item = $(this).val();        
  $("#dataval").attr("type",item)
});});
```

Comment: I want the user to write in the same textbox, when the user selects journal name option it will be entering a letter and space and he can enter a number, but when he selects ISSN option it will be entering a number